# VBA SQL Replace Into Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, vba

I have the following query and do have a problem with the syntax.
The query code looks like this:

```
query = "REPLACE INTO valuation (`ticker`,`depot_id`,`src_id`,`valuation_date`,`value`) VALUES ('" & strTicker & "','" & intDepot & "','" & intSrc & "','" & dateValuationDate & "','" & Format(CDbl(dblMktValue), "000") & "');"
```

which gives me the following string:

```
REPLACE INTO valuation (`ticker`,`depot_id`,`src_id`,`valuation_date`,`value`) VALUES ('BK001EUR','1','2','09.08.2017','14999260');
```

The fields are:

Varchar, Int, Int, Date, double

i guess i do have some problems with the quotations, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Thank you

Comment: replace the ` with `'`?

Comment: REPLACE INTO valuation ('ticker','depot_id','src_id','valuation_date','value') VALUES ('BK001EUR','1','2','09.08.2017','14999260');

this string doesnt work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely getting errors on your numeric data, so you need to remove the unneeded quotes.  Try this:

```
query = "REPLACE INTO valuation (`ticker`,`depot_id`,`src_id`,`valuation_date`,`value`) VALUES ('" & strTicker & "'," & intDepot & "," & intSrc & ",'" & dateValuationDate & "'," & Format(CDbl(dblMktValue), "000") & ");"
```